# Как функцией получить отсортированную строку значений с разделителем без повторений?

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, plsql

Как написать PL/SQL функцию, которая на вход принимает строку значений с разделителем по-умолчанию «;», а как результат возвращает строку в этом же формате, но со значениями без повторений и отсортированными в алфавитном порядке?

Например, результатом обработки строки:

```
test12 34;test 12;abv;abvavb;test 12;
```

будет такая строка:

```
abv;abvavb;test 12;test12 34;
```

Comment: Добавьте код, который вы уже сделали

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой способ (на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5c1816de7c765fa79606c5e46453d999)):

```
create function normalize (str varchar2, delimiter char := ';') return varchar2 is 
    ret varchar2 (32000);
begin 
    select listagg (col, ';') within group (order by col)||delimiter into ret
    from (
        select distinct trim (column_value) col
        from xmlTable (('"'||replace (str, delimiter, '","')||'"')));
    return ret;
end normalize;
/
```

Так запустить и получить результат:

```
var result varchar2
exec :result := normalize (str=>'test12 34;test 12;abv;abvavb;test 12;')

RESULT
-----------------------------
abv;abvavb;test 12;test12 34;
```

Answer (score 2):

Реализация функции на чистом PL/SQL с ассоциативной коллекцией для сохранения промежуточного результата. Причём, сохранять надо только ключи, т.к ключи ассоциативной коллекции по своей проироде - уникальны и отсортированы. Так как, нет переключения контекста выполнения, это будет наиболее эффективным по производительности решением.

```
create or replace function normalize (str varchar2, delimiter char := ';') return varchar2 is
    type aarr is table of char (1) index by varchar2 (96);
    function split (str varchar2, delimiter char) return aarr is
        type posvals is record (s int := 1, e int  := 0);
        pos posvals;
        tokens aarr; 
        len constant int := length (str);
    begin 
        <<split>> loop 
            pos.e := instr (str, delimiter, pos.s);
            exit split when pos.e = 0 and pos.s >= len;
            if pos.e = 0 then pos.e := len+1; end if; 
            tokens(substr (str, pos.s, pos.e-pos.s)) := null;
            pos.s := pos.e + length (delimiter); 
        end loop;
        return tokens;
    end split;
    function join (aa aarr, delimiter char) return varchar2 is
        key varchar2 (96) := aa.first;
        ret varchar2 (32000);
    begin
        while key is not null loop
            ret := ret||key||delimiter; 
            key := aa.next (key); 
        end loop;
        return ret;
    end join;
begin 
    return (join (split (str, delimiter), delimiter));
end normalize;
/
```

Запуск и результат ([на db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f9b429f245d2faf0c2a04e32eb0325cd)):

```
var result varchar2
exec :result := normalize (str=>'test12 34;test 12;abv;abvavb;test 12;')

RESULT
-----------------------------
abv;abvavb;test 12;test12 34;
```

Comment: @MaxU Примерно это я имел ввиду в вашей задаче с нормализацией телефонных номеров. Здесь плюс уникальность и сортировка токенов, если не нужна, то просто заменить тип коллекции на вложенную таблицу.

Comment: Впервые вижу декларацию функции внутри другой - не знал, что это поддерживается.